# ASP.NET Core app build to target Core 2.1 fails on IIS 10 server where Core 2.1 is installed

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have just setup up IIS 10 on a clean Server 2016 hosted server, and installed the following packages that I have gleaned should be on the machine to allow IIS to host ASP.NET Core applications:

```
aspnetcore-runtime-2.1.0-win-x64.exe
dotnet-hosting-2.1.0-win.exe
dotnet-runtime-2.1.0-win-x64.exe
```

I have installed my app straight into the Default Web Site and replaced all files in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\` with my app files. I also did assign the web site an app pool with no managed code, so that isn't my problem.

Last time my app was built with 2.0, and I installed the latest versions of the above packages, which I'm sure was 2.0, and the only error I had was that the command `dotnet` that IIS uses to invoke Kestrel to run the site, was not in the PATH env. variable

Now when I try and browse to `localhost` on the Server 2016 machine, it gives me the following error, found in the Windows event log:

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/DEFAULT WEB SITE' with physical
>   root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\' failed to start  process with commandline
>   'dotnet .\QuickDrive.Mvc.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 8000808c.

Initially I tried with the same build as before, which was 2.0, and when I got this error, I rebuilt the app to target 2.1. Nearly every search result and relevant SO answer I can find suggest a version conflict, but now there should at least be no version conflict between the runtime and hosting package on the server. Maybe there are other version conflicts I am not aware of though?

At very least I'm asking for some advice on how to get more detailed diagnostic information, even if I don't get an answer that tells me straight what config options and versions to check on Windows and on IIS.

Comment: You have to install the Core 2.1 **SDK** [link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-windows-x64-installer) if you want to target that in VS. Installing the runtime alone won't do it.

Comment: Thanks, @R.Richards. You should answer and I'll accept - I eventually guessed I had to install the SDK and doing so worked. However, now after upping my target framework to 2.1 I get the error I describe in my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50836389/8741

Comment: this was a migrated app?

Comment: when you published this app before did it work on 2.0, secondly when you are pusblishing it to the server in question how are you doing it?

Comment: @mvermef Ny migrated you mean from .NET 4.7 to Core, or from Core 2.0 to 2.1? I coded it from scratch in with a target frame work of Core 2.0. When I published it to 2.0 on the previous host, Server 2012, it worked. When I published it to the new host, where I had set up 2.1, it didn't work. All my publishing has been a simple folder publish, where publish outputs the files to a folder, and I copy those files up to the server and place them in `inetpub\wwwroot`, as it is the default web site for the server.

Comment: 2.0 to 2.1 did you flush the entire contents of the server when you did the copy over?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the Core SDK for whatever version you want to target in Visual Studio. Installing the runtime alone won't do the trick. You may have the restart Visual Studio afterward to see it in the list.

Here is a [link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-windows-x64-installer) to the SDK 2.1 download (the latest as of this writing).

Comment: My most heartfelt apologies. When I said I'd accept, I was somehow imagining I had only asked about the target framework, while the core of the question is actually about my app failing on the hosted server, where I get the error quoted in the question. I wish I could give you more points than just 1 upvote, but you do have my most sincere gratitude.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by running `dotnet myWesite.dll` in PowerShell, and first I found that `dotnet.exe` was not in the `PATH` environment variable, and after fixing that, running `dotnet myWesite.dll` again gave me a meaningful error message that an assembly was missing because it had not been included when I published the website.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error on the dev machine in IIS Express. MVC App stopped working all of the sudden. Eventlog gave the `0x80004005` error code.

After trying multiple suggestions, the solution to debug the wired error code was to run the app in the console:

```
[Project bin folder]> dotnet [projectname].dll
```

It appeared that during the NuGet package update, the dotnet core version was accidentally updated to 2.1.4 where as the installed version was 2.1.3
[could be a bug in Nuget manager as the update was from there]

I edited the project file to reference the available version (2.1.3) and the app started to work properly.